# What are the consequences of deleting the default webform content type provided by the webform module?

Tags: webforms, 9

I would like to delete this content type to simplify the Add content screen as we are only planning to use webforms as blocks.

What are the consequences if any of deleting the default webform content type provided by the webform module?

Comment: You may want to uninstall the webform_node submodule since that's what creates and works with the webform content type.

Comment: One approach to check out what happens and to see if it is possible at all would be to create a Drupal in a sandbox somewhere maybe locally and just try it out yourself.

Comment: Is this Drupal 7?

Comment: You could simply use permissions to limit who has access to it. Avoids any consequences, and work to segment your user roles on your project without any extra code.

Comment: @cilefen No it is Drupal 9. I did tag the question with 9.

Comment: @RyanHartman Normally that would be enough but we have a problem in that we have multiple users with Administrator level access. We already had one of those users create a webform page by accident.

Comment: I am not sure why someone would vote to close this? I read the documentation and the FAQ. I do not think this is spelled out anywhere. The webform node module itself does not have a README. Looks like the answer is to read the code which I will do if needed but was hoping to have community knowledge shared here.

Comment: So the question is that you wish to  delete the content type but without uninstalling the webform_node sub module?